# Block other bots/spiders from accessing my site except Googlebot bing and yandex

Tags: .htaccess, web-crawler, bots, googlebot

Is there any way to use .htaccess to block bots/crawlers/spiders accessing my site, excluding googlebot, bing, and yandex.

I dont care to know the names of the other bots/spiders. I want to allow only googlebot, bing, and yandex.

Please I have search the other posts but cant find this specific one.

Comment: Use `robots.txt`

Comment: some bot/spider ignore robots.txt, so that is why I want to use .htaccess